# While loop not equaling std::queue size

Tags: c++, while-loop, queue

I have this code:

```
std::queue<unsigned int> offsets;
// (fill offsets here)

DEBUG(std::to_string(offsets.size())) // print offsets.size() to console
int iterations = 0;

while (!offsets.empty())
{
    iterations++;

    unsigned int currOffset = offsets.front();
    offsets.pop();

    if (currOffset == 0)
    {
        DEBUG("breaking from while loop")
        break;
    }

    // do something with currOffset
}

DEBUG(std::to_string(iterations))
```

For some reason, `iterations` never equals `offsets.size()`. I'm not sure why this is. In my test application, `offsets.size() == 28`, but `iterations == 11`. I only break from the while loop once in this application.

Any idea why this is happening? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why you would expect `iterations` to equal `offsets.size()`?

Comment: Because the while loop should continue as long as `offsets.empty() != true`. Therefore `iterations` should increment each loop, thus equaling `offsets.size()`. At least that's how I'd expect it to work...

Comment: No, because you have a `break` right in the middle of your loop.

Comment: You literally asked your loop to stop midway through. Not sure why you expected that not to happen, then. You need to _show us_ "fill offsets here". _Show us_ your testcase. Or are we simply expected to guess? :(

Comment: Somewhat new to programming... I was under the impression that if you `break` a while loop, it just doesn't execute the rest of the code after the `break` statement and goes back to the `while(!offsets.empty())`. Whoops.

Comment: @NoahRoth: That would be the [`continue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue) keyword instead of `break`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the 11th offset is zero and the conditional break triggers before the loop reaches the end of your data structure?

Either that or `// do something with currOffset` involves popping more things from the queue.

Answer (score 1):

The if breaks the loop if front() == 0, doesn't need be empty.

```
while (!offsets.empty())
{
    iterations++;

    unsigned int currOffset = offsets.front();
    offsets.pop();

    if (currOffset == 0) // *** Here is the problem ***
    {
        DEBUG("breaking from while loop")
        break;
    }

    // do something with currOffset
}
```